# No funciona Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode

Buen día. Acabo de actualizar a Xcode 11, y queriendo actualizar una aplicación con Application Loader, no se pudo, busque en internet sobre este "error" y encontré que al parecer el Application Loader no viene incluido en esta versión. ¿Alguna sugerencia de como poder subir/actualizar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application loader fue cerrado o drepecated ahora debes usare Xcode a través del organizer o usar transporter desde la línea de comando